# $E(\cos(\sigma W_t))$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, expected-value, stochastic-integrals

$t>0$ $\sigma\neq 0$ - constant, $W_t$- Wiener process and i need to calculate $E(\cos(\sigma W_t))$.

$d(\cos(\sigma W_t))=(0+0-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\cos(\sigma W_t))dt-\sigma\sin(\sigma W_t)dW_t$

$\cos(\sigma W_t)=1-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\int_0^t\cos(\sigma W_s)ds-\sigma\int_0^t\sin(\sigma W_s)dWs$

$E(\cos(\sigma W_t))=1-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2E(\int_0^t\cos(\sigma W_s)ds)$

($E(\sigma\int_0^t\sin(\sigma W_t)dWs)=0$ because $\sin(\sigma W_t)\in M_{[0,T]}^2$)

$M_{[0,T]}^2=\left\{f:[0,T]\times\Omega\to\mathbb{R}:\text{f is adapted}, E\left(\int_0^Tf^2(t)dt\right)<\infty\right\}$

is this the end or should it still be calculated?

Comment: In order to avoid problems with the admins and end up with your question closed I suggest you to add the definition of $\sigma$ , $W_t$ and $M_{[0,T]^2$.

Comment: ok i add this information

Comment: $E(\int_0^t cos(\sigma W_s)ds)=\int_0^t E(cos(\sigma W_s)ds$ by Fubini theorem and $cos(\sigma W_s)=(e^{i\sigma W_s}+e^{-i\sigma W_s})/2$ ;then use characteristic function

Comment: But how yo use characteristic fuction? I know that $E(X^k)=\frac{\phi_X^{(k)}(0)}{i^k}$ but what the function $\phi_X(t)$ looks like in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

$$E(\cos(\sigma W_t))=1-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2E(\int_0^t\cos(\sigma W_s)ds)$$

First notice that $E(\int_0^t\cos(\sigma W_s)ds)=\int_0^t E(\cos(\sigma W_s)ds$ thanks to Fubini's theorem (notice that $\cos(\sigma W_s)$ is continuous, and hence integrable in the compact $[0,t]$).

Then using the exponential representation of the cosine you have

$$\cos(\sigma W_s)=\frac{e^{i\sigma W_s}+e^{i(-\sigma)W_s}}2$$

Then $$E\cos(\sigma W_s)=E\left(\frac{e^{i\sigma W_s}+e^{i(-\sigma)W_s}}2\right)$$

Remember that $W_s$ is a gaussian r.v. hence using the characteristic function (not the moment generating function) you have

$$E\cos(\sigma W_s)=\frac 1 2 (2e^{-(1/2) \sigma^2 s})=e^{-(1/2) \sigma^2 s}$$

Then 
$$E(\cos(\sigma W_t))=1-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 \int_0^t e^{-(1/2) \sigma^2 s}$$

The result should be fairly obvious at this point.

Comment: Thank you :) So if i have to compute $E\sin(\sigma W_s)=E\left(\frac{e^{i\sigma W_s}-e^{i(-\sigma)W_s}}{2i}\right)$ the result is zero so $E(\sin(\sigma W_t))=-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2E(\int_0^t\sin(\sigma W_s)ds)=0$?

Comment: yes, it seems right! don't forget to accept the answer and upvote it if you found it helpful! :)